# Add active class in PHP for category

Tags: php

I have tried to add active class for my category list

```
<?php

  $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
  $query="SELECT * FROM `category` ORDER BY name ASC" ; 
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<li><a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></li>

 <?php } ?>
```

When click on category list, I need to add class 'active' for list.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. Please take the time to revise your question, try to think from _our_ point of view: we know _nothing_ about what you tried, did, failed, wondered.... There is an `edit` link below your question text. _Use it..._

Comment: What's your problem? It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am getting from your question is you have to add `active` class in your anchor tag which match `$id`. Try this code

```
<?php

            $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
 $query="SELECT * FROM `category` ORDER BY name ASC" ; 
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                ?>
              <li><a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class ="<?=($id == $row['id']) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></li>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="<?php echo ($row['id'] == $choosen_id) ? 'active' : ""; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></li>
```